# Json.NET: Deserializing Json object returns null C# object

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I have this Json object:

```
{
    "ComplementoCartaPorte": [
        {
            "RFCImportador": "IJD840224QD2",
            "Pedimentos": [
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000518",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO1IN",
                    "Remesa": 1
                },
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000528",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO2A1",
                    "Remesa": 0
                }
            ],
            "Archivos": {
                "FolioFiscal": "287d57c7-9132-4234-9268-28e984e7cdf1",
                "PDF": "PD94",
                "XML": "PD94"
            }
        },
        {
            "RFCImportador": "MJD960223MV9",
            "Pedimentos": [
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000519",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO3IN",
                    "Remesa": 1
                },
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000520",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO4A1",
                    "Remesa": 0
                }
            ],
            "Archivos": {
                "FolioFiscal": "587d57c7-9133-4234-9268-28e984e7cdg7",
                "PDF": "AM92",
                "XML": "AM92"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to de-serialize it to a C# object of this class:

```
// Top level class
public class ComplementoCartaPorte
{
    // Only one field, an array
    public Complemento[] Complemento { get; set; }
}

// Array elements of "Complemento" field
public class Complemento
{
    public string RFCImportador { get; set; }

    // Array Field
    public Pedimento[] Pedimentos { get; set; }

    public Archivo Archivos { get; set; }
}

// Array elements of "Pedimentos" field
public class Pedimento
{
    public string NumPedimento { get; set; }
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
    public int Remesa { get; set; }
}

public class Archivo
{
    public string FolioFiscal { get; set; }
    public string PDF { get; set; }
    public int XML { get; set; }
}
```

I try to de-serialize like this (C#):

```
ComplementoCartaPorte comp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ComplementoCartaPorte>(json_string);
```

The "comp" resulting object is of type "ComplementoCartaPorte", but it has only one property of type "Complemento", which is null. I expected it to be an array of "Complemento" objects with data.

Can somebody please shed some light on this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use List < ComplementoCartaPorte > instead of ComplementoCartaPorte

```
List<ComplementoCartaPorte> comp = JsonConvert
.DeserializeObject<Root>(json_string).ComplementoCartaPorte;
```

classes

```
public class Pedimento
    {
        public string NumPedimento { get; set; }
        public string Referencia { get; set; }
        public int Remesa { get; set; }
    }

    public class Archivos
    {
        public string FolioFiscal { get; set; }
        public string PDF { get; set; }
        public string XML { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComplementoCartaPorte
    {
        public string RFCImportador { get; set; }
        public List<Pedimento> Pedimentos { get; set; }
        public Archivos Archivos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<ComplementoCartaPorte> ComplementoCartaPorte { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks a lot! Also, thanks to your answer I can now better understand how this thing works. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the json above might be helpful to see in this case to see why this is happening.

Starting with `{}` we have an unnamed object. This is our wrapper / root object.

On that object we have a property, `ComplementoCartaPorte`.
This object has an array of objects as denoted by `[]` with `{},{}` inside.

But this structure doesn't align with our existing classes.
`ComplementoCartaPorte` has a property that is an array property called `Complemento` of `Complemento` objects

If we want those objects to be deserialized as `Complemento` then we need to adjust the json a bit.

```
{
"ComplementoCartaPorte": {
    "Complemento": [
        {
            "RFCImportador": "IJD840224QD2",
            "Pedimentos": [
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000518",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO1IN",
                    "Remesa": 1
                },
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000528",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO2A1",
                    "Remesa": 0
                }
            ],
            "Archivos": {
                "FolioFiscal": "287d57c7-9132-4234-9268-28e984e7cdf1",
                "PDF": "PD94",
                "XML": "PD94"
            }
        },
        {
            "RFCImportador": "MJD960223MV9",
            "Pedimentos": [
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000519",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO3IN",
                    "Remesa": 1
                },
                {
                    "NumPedimento": "80034680000520",
                    "Referencia": "REFPEDIMENTO4A1",
                    "Remesa": 0
                }
            ],
            "Archivos": {
                "FolioFiscal": "587d57c7-9133-4234-9268-28e984e7cdg7",
                "PDF": "AM92",
                "XML": "AM92"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Notice the adjusting of the object for the ComplementoCartaPorte property an addition of the property for `Complemento` after opening the `ComplementoCartaPorte` object.

Then we can add the following class to be our wrapper

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public ComplementoCartaPorte ComplementoCartaPorte { get; set; }
}

Wrapper comp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json_string);
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. I am new to JSON and JSON.Net and your answer helped me a lot to better understand how this thing works. Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the JSON, though I am allowed  to change the C# classes. I will go that route now that I understand the subject better. Thanks again.